# stack level too deep : rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

Getting error when trying to pass an optional argument to a rails model method.
My model is like below

```
Class Antigen 
has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
```

I want to do

```
antigen = Antigen.first
antigen.projects(injection)
```

or even

```
antigen.projects
```

### Model Method to pass arguement

```
def projects(injection=nil)
    if injection == nil 
       return projects
    else 
       ..do something with injection and then pass projects
    end
end
```

Why is this not working

Comment: `Stack level too deep` is usually a endless loop, like a recursive method calling itself, again and again... With that in mind, try to look again at your code and find the error -- also, don't use `injection == nil` but `injection.nil?` (or even better: `injection.present?`) -- also, please post the full implementation of `projects` method, We need to know the entire method to see from where the error comes

Comment: Hi Yoshiji projects is the general HABTM association in rails. Project is a different class than Antigen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling projects (which you have just overriden) use super:

```
def projects(injection=nil)
  if injection == nil 
    return super()
  else 
   ..do something with injection and then pass projects
  end
end
```

I would refactor it slightly to get rid of one level of abstraction:

```
def projects(injection=nil)
  return super() unless injection
  #..do something with injection and then pass projects
end
```

UPDATE:

Since you're using rails 2.3.8 super cannot be used to access association metho. Instead try:

```
class Model < AR::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :proxy_projects, class_name: 'Projects'
  private :proxy_projects

  def projects(injection=nil)
    return proxy_projects unless injection
    #..do something with injection and then pass projects
  end
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `projects'